# Regex to check for first 3 consecutive digits

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Would like to find out how to validate a string such that **first 3 consecutive** digits cannot be 8 or 9 consecutively? Example:

```
88839182 (not valid) 
99923213 (not valid)
98188823 (valid) 
98939117 (valid)
```

Tried using `s.match("([98]){3}")` but it doesn't seem to work, as it takes in 989 for first 3 character too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following regex for identifying the 3 consecutive 8 or 9 :

```
"(?:([98])\1\1)"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dA7lJ7/1)

And for matching the numbers that you want you can use a negative look ahead to match numbers that doesn't precede by 3 consecutive 9 or 8:

```
^(?!(?:([98])\1\1)).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dA7lJ7/2)

Also as a nice suggestion by @Luv2code you can use following regex that will forced your regex engine to match digits:

```
(?=^\d+$)(?!([98])\1\1)\d+
```

Comment: hi! thanks for your reply. i only want the first 3 consecutive digits though. subsequent consecutive digits are considered valid.

Comment: @Kasra, great solution.  I would point out that IF the requirement is to capture only digits (that wasn't specific, but based on the examples how I interpreted the requirements), that would be a different regex.  Your regex will match 123abc, foo, "hello world," etc.  To limit it to only digits:  "(?=^\d+$)(?!([98])\1\1)\d+"  The first assertion ensures the entire field is digits.  Second assertion is yours. Finally, I used \d instead of dot so if you want 123 in "a 123 z" change ^ and $ to \b and voila!

Comment: @Luv2code Good point actually since OP is talking about digits i should used `\d` instead of dot! and about `(?=^\d+$)` surely you're right its a nice solution. thanks for suggestion and correcting me! ;)

Comment: @Kasra, you're welcome, but I did not mean it as a correction so much as a supplement. Your solution was perfect for what OP asked for, I just wanted to add, "if OP meant this then this," but we're not really clear on whether or not that was one of the requirements or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(?!(?:888|999))\d+\b
```

You can simply do this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0iN5/3

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your problem statement is correct: You want to (a) find the first triple digit in your digit string, and (b) reject the string if this is 888 or 999. So do it in two steps:

1. Find and extract the first three consecutive digits.
2. Reject the string if the match is 888 or 999.

The regexp to match three consecutive digits is simply `(\d)\1\1`. The rest depends on your programming language (which you don't specify); it almost certainly a way to return the contents of the first match in your digit string.

Answer (score 0):

Another, simpler way of defining the problem is "does not start with 888 or 999",

It find *invalid* data:

```
s.match("^(999|888)")
```

To find *valid* data;

```
!s.match("^(999|888)")
```

Comment: That matches strings that *do* start with `888` or `999`, though.

Comment: @joey yes - that's what OP's code does (and he complained it *also* match 989...)

Comment: Ah, fair enough; I missed that part. It's just that these questions often originate with regex-based validation where all you can do is supply a regex for *valid* values and thus cannot write any code to invert the result, in which case this has to be solved with a negative lookahead.

Comment: @Joey Agreed - often unclear as to whether positive or negative matches are needed. Also, safer to `!` to method call than negative lookahead if possible, because some engines don't support look arounds.